# How do you filter a row based on the criteria of a column with two values in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to filter row A based on if it has BOTH a value "Found" AND "None" in the D column. Essentially, I want to see which rows have entries with both at least 1 Found and at least 1 None value.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Are some rows in column A merged?  For instance the cell that starts E7, is that a merged cell?  Non-normalized data is *much* harder to work with in formulas.  The “normalized” approach for a data table would be for the “E7T069965” to repeat 3 times, appearing in rows  2, 3, and 4.  This makes each row an independent entity that can be acted on more simply.

Comment: @Max Hi, yes they are merged. I figured that might make it more difficult. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: My question is, can you un-merge them?  Were they merged manually, for aesthetic reason?  Or were the brought into Excel already merged because of the way an upstream data source organized them?  If you can un-merge them, there’s a pretty straightforward solution.

Comment: @Max The data was brought in from Tableau already merged like that. I'll have to look into how to unmerge them, I wasn't sure if that was a possibility.

Comment: If needed we can create an excel formula that “re-hydrates” a new column that has a one-to-one relationship.  Do you have O365?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper column like the example below. It adds 1 if found is listed for that item, and adds 1 if again if None if found for that item. So if the value is 2 then it has both a found and a none.

=(IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"Found")>0,1,0)
+(IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"None")>0,1,0)))

[image]

I hope this helps